# How to create lower level network packets in node.js

Tags: c, node.js, network-programming

Am working on a project where i require some packet creation, such as ICMP ECHO and other packets where I can start the TCP 3-way handshake. What is the best way to do it node.js? I don't see any packet manipulating libraries like scappy (python) in node.js. All i have for now is node-pcap which is used to monitor packets. But how do i create new packets from scratch?

Comment: ICMP implementation for node using C binding to V8 https://github.com/wearefractal/pinger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node.js doesn't currently offer a raw socket API, and as far as I'm aware, nobody has implemented it as an npm module yet either, so I don't think this is possible at the moment.

Comment: comments shown same day of post and later clearly so that it is possible. Plus node-gyp clearly allows low level access via c++ to raw sockets or libpcap interfacing.

Comment: See other answer for npm module

Answer (score 3):

There is a module on npm that gives you access to raw sockets: https://npmjs.org/package/raw-socket

Answer (score 1):

You could start with node-pcap and add packet injecton to it's c++ bindings to v8. You could probably also open a specific device like tuntap on Linux and inject packets using a stream. I don't know of any bindings that allow for arbitrary ioctls in node, but they probably exist.