# Best practice for seperating Node TCP stream into packets?

Tags: node.js, networking, tcp

I'm using Node's TCP client for a real-time backend for my game, which communicates in a fixed-length protocol. For example,

```
0x00 - Connection Request
int32 Identifier
4 bytes long

0x01 - Position Update
int32 positionx
int32 positiony
8 bytes long
```

Of course, Node works like this

```
socket.on("data", (data) => {
   // Arbitary buffer of bytes
})
```

I only want to process packets one at a time once they've been recieved in full, but what's the best way to *A: continue adding to a buffer until the full packet is recieved* and *B: make sure not to include the data of a second packet in the first one*

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865004/how-to-create-lower-level-network-packets-in-node-js

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it!

```
function readData(data, socket) {
    console.log("Read chunk of data " + data.length + " bytes long")

    while (data.length > 0) {
        if (expectsNewPacket) {
            packetBuffer = new Buffer(0)
            currentPacketInfo = getPacketInformationFromHeader(data)
            data = currentPacketInfo.slicedData
            console.log("New packet: ident " + currentPacketInfo.ident + ", length: " + currentPacketInfo.length)
            expectedLengthRemaining = currentPacketInfo.length
            expectsNewPacket = false
        }


        // If the data is more than the rest of the packet, just concat the rest of the packet and remove it from our block
        if (data.length >= expectedLengthRemaining) {
            packetBuffer = Buffer.concat([packetBuffer, data.slice(0, expectedLengthRemaining)]) 
            data = data.slice(expectedLengthRemaining)

            processPacket(packetBuffer, socket)
            expectsNewPacket = true
        } else {
            // Or if the data length is less than what we need, just add all that we can and we'll add more later
            packetBuffer = Buffer.concat([packetBuffer, data.slice(0, data.length)])
            data = data.slice(data.length)
        }
    }
}
```